# Rename [monkey-island] and related tags → [the-secret-of-monkey-island] etc

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

We have tags such as [monkey-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island) that were made when we had a 25 character tag limit. Now that we have a 35 character tag limit, I propose that we expand these out

- [monkey-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island) → [the-secret-of-monkey-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-secret-of-monkey-island) (6 questions)
- [monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-se) → [the-secret-of-monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-secret-of-monkey-island-se) (3 questions)
- [monkey-island-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2) → [monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge) (6 questions)
- [monkey-island-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-se) → [monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se) (6 questions)

However, I think that [monkey-island-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-series) should remain as is, given that all games in the series do have "Monkey Island" in their name, but no other common words.

Comment: I say go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done:**

- [monkey-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island) → [the-secret-of-monkey-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-secret-of-monkey-island)
- [monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-se) → [the-secret-of-monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-secret-of-monkey-island-se)
- [monkey-island-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2) → [monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge)
- [monkey-island-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-se) → [monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se)